# Maven - deliver jar files with OS indication in file name

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We provide a library and want to deliver jar files with file names based on the OS distribution on which we created the jar files with GraalVM.
We have same code but build the jars on different platforms and then we would like to see automagically proper file names.
For example, xxx-1.1-linux.jar and xxx-1.1-windows.jar or something similar for the OS distribution indication.
How could that be done best, using shade plugin or assembly plugin or both, or any other way that could be done?
Also I would like to know the details in the form of sample pom contents, if possible.

Project https://github.com/ReneUmmels/maventest.git does not do what I want. The SNAPSHOT.jar is installed, while I want SNAPSHOT-windows.jar to be installed:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ histogram-fit-impl ---
[INFO] Installing C:\GITHUB_SAMPLES\maventest\algorithms-native\histogram-fit\histogram-fit-impl\target\histogram-fit-impl-1.1-SNAPSHOT-Windows 10.jar to C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\maventest\histogram-fit-impl\1.1-SNAPSHOT\histogram-fit-impl-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Karl Heinz, thanks for the question.
We have a project with sub-modules. When the sub-module delivering the jar has pom.xml as in description (added just now) then the following is done which is renaming back to original file name (without "Windows 10"):

22-Feb-2022 22:33:42 [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xxx-impl ---
22-Feb-2022 22:33:42 [INFO] Installing ...\xxx\histogram-fit-impl\target\histogram-fit-impl-1.1-SNAPSHOT-Windows 10.jar to ...\${project.basedir}\.m2\repository\com\asml\algorithms\wfa\xxx-impl\1.1-SNAPSHOT\xxx-impl-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Please edit the question add the information...in comments it's useless apart from that using very old versions of plugins. Please make an example project on github or alike to show the whole structure of your project...

Comment: working on getting sample code available.

Comment: Project now available in github, see description.